# Conditionally select a data frame or dataset , but incorrectly receiving list

Tags: r, function, parameters

I am trying to create a function to conditionally select the data frame.

However, I keep receiving a list of the first column of values which I can't understand rather than the actual dataset.

```
func1=function(type) ifelse(type=='B', mtcars, iris)
data=func1('A')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
func1=function(type) ifelse(type=='B', return(mtcars), return(iris))
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised this works. Perhaps add some explanation for why it does, given what I found in `?ifelse`?

Answer (score 0):

See `?ifelse` -- the arguments `yes` and `no` are supposed to be the same length as `test`. Your `test` is length one, so the output is coerced to be so as well.

Just use a regular `if` statement:

```
func1 <- function(type) if (type == "B") mtcars else iris
```

`ifelse` is suited for logical comparisons on *vectors*, e.g.

```
ifelse(runif(10) > .5), "Heads", "Tails")
```

Is a quick-and-dirty (and inefficient) way to get coin flip draws.